# How to change Locale of a Tizen Watch Emulator for testing App

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-emulator, tizen-studio

My App works good using Western settings, but I just got noised that it does not perform optimal in some Asian settings. I would like to use the Emulator to debug the issue. How is the Locale set on the Emulator?

I have searched the net and all standard resources on how to do this setting, but found nothing.

Any hint on how this is done is much appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try to change language setting?

Setting - Device - Language - ...

Comment: How did I miss that one!  Thanx!